# Disable button until new year

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I have the following screen in my applicaton:

[image]

I'm trying create a functionality to disable the "Execute" button until the next year arrives when the "Delivered" button is click. At this moment i'm trying to use a Session variable but i'm struggling a bit implementing this functionality correctly.

Can any one advice me of the best way to do something like this?

Thank you

Comment: If it is important, that the button can't be used before new year, I'd suggest you to not to add the functionality to the code untill it's the time to execute it. Via the Dev Tools it is too easy to enable the button and execute the code attached to it. What comes to the question itself, we'd like to see the code for the button, manipulating an image is not fruitful ...

Comment: @Mratinho You should avoid using session for things like that when ever possible. It gets out of hand and hard to manage pretty quickly. In this case you should likely remove the functionality until you need it. If you want to leave it in can just use `Enabled='<%# DateTime.Now.Year > 2018 %>'` on the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for a **front-end** solution, you can do something like this. In this case, the button won't be enabled if the year is before 2019:

```js
var year = new Date().getFullYear();

if (year < 2019) {
 document.querySelector('#disabled').disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<button id="disabled">Wait until 2019, please</button>
```

**BUT** you will need to verify the date on the server-side too, otherwise everyone could trick your system.